# How do you find the coefficient of $x$ in $(x + 1)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I want to learn how can I find out the coefficient of the variable $x$ in the expression $(x + 1)^2$. It is a case of a perfect square expansion.

Comment: This is simple enough that you can expand it and find the coefficient to the $x$ term, but for more complicated powers, you can use the binomial theorem.

Comment: You should learn the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** $(x+1)^2$ can be expanded as follows $$(x+1)^2=(x+1)(x+1)=x^2+x+x+1=x^2+2x+1$$

Comment: So, is the answer x + 2 + 1?

Comment: No, coefficient of $x$ in expansion $x^2+2x+1$ is $2$. So answer is $2$

Comment: Can you please tell me how?

Comment: Well, I showed you the expansion of $(x+1)^2=x^2+\color{red}{2}x+1$. Look at the coefficient of $x$ in $\color{red}{2}x$ which is equal to $\color{red}{2}$

Comment: Ok, but won't x and 1 also be a part of the coefficient?

Comment: No, $x$ and  $1$ are not part of coefficient. It's just $2$. You can accept my answer now by ticking.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and the constant term will also be 2 I presume?

Comment: No, constant term will be $1\times 1=1$

Comment: Can you please tell me how?

Comment: The constant term in the expansion $x^2+2x+\color{red}{1}$ is $\color{red}{1}$

Answer (score 0):

This is the distributive property of the multiplication: $(a+b)c=ac+bc$.

What is $(x+a)^2$? Well,
$$(x+a)^2=(x+a)(x+a)$$
Let's write one of the factors $(x+a)=c$, and distribute:
$$(x+a)^2=(x+a)c=xc+ac$$
Replacing $c$ back to $x+a$ we get
$$(x+a)^2=(x+a)(x+a)=x(x+a)+a(x+a)$$
And we distribute again
$$(x+a)^2=x(x+a)+a(x+a)=x^2+xa+ax+a^2$$
At the end we get 
$$(x+a)^2=x^2+2ax+a^2$$